# Several C# classes with access to XAML page MAUI

Tags: c#, class, xaml, maui

I have a XAML page, bounded with the c# class `MainPage`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
    xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2022/maui/toolkit"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Project"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
    x:Class="Project.MainPage">

    <Label x:Name="l1"/>
    <Label x:Name="l2"/>
</ContentPage>
```

Here is the c# class MainPage, it has access to the labels `l1` and `l2`

```cs
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SetText1() => l1.Text = "Text 1";
}
```

**Can i create second class with access to the `l1` and `l2`**? And if yes, **how will it look like**?

I tried: (**doesn't work**)

```cs
public partial class Class2 : ContentPage
{
    public Class2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void SetText2() => l2.Text = "Text 2";
}
```

And then put `Class2` to the `x:Class` in the XAML page

```xml
x:Class="Project.MainPage, Project.Class2">
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You cannot access UI elements from one View in the code-behind of another View, at least not without passing references around, which should be avoided because it leads to tight coupling. What do you actually want to achieve?

Comment: You might want to expand on what is exactly you are trying to accomplish.
Also, look into how partial classes work. In your example MainPage.xaml and MainPage.xaml.cs are compiled to a single class. Your example of Class2 does not work because l1 and l2 are defined in MainPage but you are inheriting from ContentPage which is a base class.

Comment: @Jason i want to separate work with `l1` and `l2`. This is example, my really situation is more difficult. Of course i can work with `l1` and `l2` in one class, but it will be uncomfortable.

Comment: you should really investigate using MVVM rather than tightly coupling your logic to your view.  Or if you can provide a better explanation of what you're trying to do we can offer better advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I suggest you use [MessagingCenter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-7.0) to approach.

If you want to change the Label in `MainPage` from `Class 2 page`, you just Subscribe `Class 2 page` from `MainPage`, and call `Send` method to inform `MainPage` to edit the text of `l2`.

**MainPage:**

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<B,string> (this, "Tag", (sender,arge) =>  
{  
    // Do something set the text of l2 
})
```

**Class 2:**

```
 MessagingCenter.Send<B, string>(this, "Tag", "Text 2");
```

**Update:**

Thanks for @ewerspej's comment.

As `MessagingCenter` has been deprecated in .NET 7 and replaced with `WeakReferenceMessenger` in the [CommunityToolkit.Mvvm](https://www.nuget.org/packages/CommunityToolkit.Mvvm) NuGet package. For more information, see [Messenger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/mvvm/messenger).

For more information, please refer this doc:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/fundamentals/messagingcenter?view=net-maui-7.0

Comment: You should use `WeakReferenceManager` from the Community Toolkit instead of the outdated `MessagingCenter`. Microsoft even recommends using it and so does the MAUI team, because it handles object references better. It even says so under the link you posted.

Comment: @ewerspej Thanks for pointing that out. I've updated it.